# Youtube rss displays Forbidden

Tags: youtube, rss

Im having a problem with youtube rss. a week ago, the rss feed of this "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/M_vDwwo498dNg3FADnV-vQ/newsubscriptionvideos" worked really good. It displays my last suscribers videos. But since 2 days, it says "forbidden". I did not do anything into youtube since 2 weeks in my configuration, so i dont know why it says that. But if i replace, "newsubscriptionvideos" for "uploads" it show my uploads, so i think its a problem on youtube, or i dont know. Someone have an idea?

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/M_vDwwo498dNg3FADnV-vQ/newsubscriptionvideos
gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/M_vDwwo498dNg3FADnV-vQ/uploads

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this has anything to do with this, but this API is deprecated.

And it looks like new API has no replacement. Here is the issue http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3946

Answer (score 1):

It's working again !
Try it again

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/M_vDwwo498dNg3FADnV-vQ/newsubscriptionvideos

Comment: :D YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEH

Comment: This method works ONLY if you turn off the "Keep all my subscriptions private" in YouTube settings. Then use the user-id string from the account information, advanced page.